# prevent UILabel repeat added to custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-cell

I have a customCell and I need to add more than one UILabel as "tag" to each cell,
My code is like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *ID = @"topicCell";
    MSPTopicCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ID];
    NSArray *labelArray = [TopicLabelArr objectAt:index.row];
    for (int i = 0; i < [labelArray count]; i++) {
        UILabel *tmpLabel = [UILabel alloc]initwithFrame .....];
        tmpLabel.text = [labelArray objectAt:i];
        [cell.view addSubview:tmpLabel];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I use Xib to create the custom cell. 
What I need is make the for-loop only execute one time on each cell.
However, there are many rows in tableView, and the labels will be  created repeatly every times when I scroll up and down. How to improve it? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: set a bool flag before you add the label.

Comment: Update your question with your complete `cellForAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: the code has been update . Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, you are not creating a new `MSPTopicCell` you (as the name of the method says) reuse a cell.

What does that mean ? You obviously need at least as many cell as how much you are displaying at the same time, but once your start scrolling, the cells which disappear of your scrollview are reused.

The labels you add to the subview are added overtime, even on a reused cell which already got some subviews added, which produce your issue.

There are many ways to fix it, here are some examples:

- You can remove the subviews added before adding new ones. Add the following line before your for loop using the following code:

  ```
  view.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() }
  ```
- Use a custom tag for your labels so you can see it they already exist or not :

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < [labelArray count]; i++) {
      UILabel *tmpLabel = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:100+i];
      if (tmpLabel == nil) 
      {
          tmpLabel = [UILabel alloc]initwithFrame .....];
          tmpLabel.tag = 100 + i;
          [cell.view addSubview:tmpLabel];
      }
      tmpLabel.text = [labelArray objectAt:i];
  }
  ```
- The best solution, in my opinion, since you already use an `UITableViewCell` subclass : simply directly add some `UILabel` properties on your `MSPTopicCell` class, so you don't have to create it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. But maybe this case is not adapted for you since the number of labels depend of the `labelArray`, which dependents of the position of the cell.

Comment: Don't recommend using tags, pleeeeease! They are literally the worst way to approach this. Delete the second (and first) part from your answer and you'll get a +1. I can't give +1 atm though as you recommend using tags.

Comment: Sorry for showing it, I just wanted to show multiple approaches. I know they are bad and prone to error, it was just fort culture. Do you think I should keep them in the answer for culture or remove this part so this part of iOS framework stays hidden ?

Comment: it's up to you really. I think it's enough to show the subclass way. That's general the best approach to this. The problem with tags is that people then begin relying on the uiview to hold random bits of data. I always try to discourage it :-)

Comment: I usually always use the third case, but the numbers of labels is able to change, so I am now sure how to set it properly. Maybe a method `configureWithArray` into the `MSPTopicCell` class, which will handle the creation and destruction of labels, so it is hidden from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`part

Comment: I guess a better approach would be to use a collection view inside the cell. Or possibly just a collection view to manage the labels instead of a table view?

Comment: Since the content of the cell doesn't look scrollable (the labels are added directly to its view), I'll go for a collection view within the cell, thus you can keep the `section` part of the `indexPath` for the tableview, instead of using it for "simulate" the cells and use the `row` property for the labels  if a single collection view is used. But I'm just making assumption about the look of the tableview, so it's really depending of the desired look.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot. I have resolved my problem by the third way you mentioned. Because the label count won't larger than 10, so I created 10 uilabels first. then pass value to the cell. Thanks again for your help! MichaëlAzevedo  &&  Fogmeister

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `UIView` which will include all your `UILabel`. However when you **reuse** the cell at the beginning just remove that view from superview. 
So masterview will be **removed** from your cell.

i.e

```
[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101] removeFromSuperview]
UIView *yourViewName = [[UIView alloc]init];
// set your view's frame based on cell.
yourViewName.tag = 101;
for (int i = 0; i < [labelArray count]; i++) {
    UILabel tmpLabel = (UILabel )[self viewWithTag:100+i];
    if (tmpLabel == nil) 
    {
        tmpLabel = [UILabel alloc]initwithFrame .....];
        tmpLabel.tag = 100 + i;
        [yourViewName addSubview:tmpLabel];
    }
    tmpLabel.text = [labelArray objectAt:i];
}
[cell.contentView addSubView:yourViewName];
```

This process will speed up your cell's scrolling performance as well.

Hope this answer helped you.